# Passport node.js local authentication not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, express, passport.js

I am trying to implement *passport + express + mongodb* functionality of local authentication, but it doesn't seem to work. All of the examples, including the one from the official page has the line 
`app.use(app.router);`, but I am using express 4.9 and I get the error :

```
Error: 'app.router' is deprecated!
```

If I remove it, I only get redirected to unsuccessful login, without even entering the  LocalStrategy callback.
I would appreciate any help and suggestion how should I substitute the deprecated line.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to remove that line -- in Express 4.x this is no longer needed -- some of the passport docs are just out of date.

Also: you may want to check out [express-stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/) as an alternative to passport if you're trying to store user accounts. Depending on your application's usage, it might be a lot simpler.